# How to convert '1,0' to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, int

As the title says, how would I go about converting `'1,0' into 1,0` I've been getting  `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,0'`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `1,0` is generally not valid syntax for a float. You have to use `1.0`. Second you can't convert `1.0` to an int, as this is a float. Use `float("1.0")` instead. If you need an int you can `round` the parsed float, e.g.

```
round(float("1.0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
int(float('1,0'.replace(',', '.')))
```